# IntelliJ Pycharm how to move caret to a certain nth character of the row

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

In the Pycharm Editor, say my caret now is at the 30th row, the first character.
What is the shortcut to move to the 30th row, the 80th character?

The recommended line length for Python is 80. When working on someone else' code using 120 character length, I found myself frequently need to move my caret to the 80th character and hit an Enter.

Comment: Not really what you're asking for but usually if you click the little yellow icon that pops up and let pycharm reformat it will do it for all the lines. This saves you from having to go press enter line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can move to a specific character location in a line by** :

1. Press `ctrl + g` to open the Go to line Column dialog box.
2. The position of the caret is the default value in the dialog box. you can change the column number to character position(in this case 80).(no need to change the line number)

**In pycharm there is a automatic line wrapping feature that allows you to insert line breaks automatically.**

[image]

Go to:

**Settings -> Editor -> Code Style** 
 and type in the character position you want to wrap at and check Wrap on typing checkbox. You can use visual guides to get an indicated where the 80th column is and  **ctrl + alt + l** reformat the code to fit within the the margin.

Edit: To reformat the code without using the shortcut,

- > Go to **code -> Reformat Code** in the menu bar.

Comment: If you don't want hard wrapping, the Visual Guides setting can be set to show you where 80 columns is at.

Comment: my ctrl+alt+I mapped to "auto-indent" on Windows. Would you please update your answer, instead of giving the short key directly, providing how to reformat to code to fit 80 from the IDE?

Comment: modified the answer. Please refer it. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Settings -> Code Style, you can set "Visual guides" to 80 columns. This will give a vertical bar in your editor to show you the 80 column width. You can then press Alt-Ctrl-L to reformat your code to fit within that width. This will also format your code to conform with all other PEP8 conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda easy. But I'm not sure if we have a hotkey to do it.
Here is an instruction on how to do it.

On the right of the status bar (the bottom bar), there is a spot looks like this `27:13`. It means your cursor is on line 30th and on row 15th
You can go to any line and row by clicking on this spot an input your numbers

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained in words what is shown in your image. Sometimes the link to the image stops working goes badly and an explanation works so that you're answer still has the answer even if that happens (or if someone for some reason can't view the link.)

Comment: Agreed. I just modified the answer.